# Computer Displayed BSOD, Shows pixelated patterns, occasionally restarts, is stuck in this state

Tags: bsod, crash

My laptop shows me images similar to this one. It occasionally shows the Blue Screen of Death, restarts, and shows me a similar image until it restarts again autonomously (even when the screen is closed). It repeats this until the battery dies. I cannot interact with it in any standard way (besides pointlessly pressing the on and off button).

[image: photo of weird screen]

I was running a trustworthy program on my computer when my screen froze and showed me the BSOD. It gave me four options, and I was eventually able to save all of its data to a USB stick. Despite it suggesting I reinstall Windows, it didn't work for some reason. Any attempts to do anything led to the computer returning to the same four options. It occasionally showed images similar to the one here.
It stayed like that for a couple of days. We checked it in about a month (which is right now) and it now shows what it described in the first paragraph.
In case this matters, my laptop is a Windows 11, bought less than a year ago. Interestingly enough, the BSOD was not distorted in any way, which means that the error is not in the screen but the computer itself. All programs I have installed seem to be trustworthy and are used by at least one million people each. I am also completely sure I did not install any additional data that could have contained a virus (e.g. a Minecraft map).

Comment: Most probably a hardware defect like a faulty GPU. If less than a year old it should still be in warranty.

Comment: Did you note down the error codes from the BSODs ?

Comment: You state, " bought less than a year ago." You might try reseating RAM, but do nothing to violate warranty. If you cannot even enter BIOS/UEFI, it's a **hardware** issue. Salvage any data you need by putting the drive in another machine or external drive enclosure, erase any personal info and return it.